# Sorting/ordering geometry column by longitude in Geopandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting, gis, geopandas

I have a bunch of POINT Z (x,y,z) values in a Geopandas geometry column. I want to take these points and construct a LINE which in turn I can buffer to create a POLYGON.

To generate the line I use:

`lineStringObj = LineString([[a.x, a.y] for a in gdf.geometry.values])`

Which is fine when all the point values are nicely ordered North/South in latitude. However, my dataframe needs to be ordered East/West in longitude so when I create my linestringobj the points join in a nice straight line rather than zigzagging based on the latitude order. How can I sort/re-order my dataframe base on the longitude (`gdf.geometry.values.x`) value of the geometry column?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.argsort`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) to get the sort order:

```py
gdf = gdf.iloc[
   gdf.geometry.x.argsort().values
]
```

At this point you can construct your linestring with the same code you have above.